# Extract coordinate values from Leaflet marker to Java Script variable

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am trying to incorporate pgRouting layer from geoserver to my HTML GUI. For this I have been trying to make a function that will take coordinate values from a Leaflet marker and feed them into my specified parameters. The parameters will act as start and end points for the routing layer. I can't seem to get any lat/lon values to enter into my *var viewparams*. The code is as follows:

```
var params = {
    LAYERS: 'IST_Mosaic:pgRouting',
    FORMAT: 'image/png',
    SERVICE: 'WMS',
    request: 'GetMap'
}
var selectedPoint = null;

var sourceMarker = L.marker([33.5183, 73.1789], {
    draggable: true
})
.on("dragend", function(e) {
    selectedPoint = e.target.getLatLng(); console.log(selectedPoint)
    getRoute(); 
})
.addTo(map); 

// draggbale marker for destination point.Note the marker is initialized with an initial destination positon
var targetMarker = L.marker([33.5191, 73.1768], {
    draggable: true
})
.on("dragend", function(e) {
    selectedPoint = e.target.getLatLng(); console.log(selectedPoint)
    getRoute(); 
})
.addTo(map); 

function getRoute(){
    var start = sourceMarker.getLatLng();  
    var end = targetMarker.getLatLng();   
    var viewparams = [
        'x1:' + start[0], 'y1:' + start[1],
        'x2:' + end[0], 'y2:' + end[1]
      ];
      params.viewparams = viewparams.join(';'); console.log(viewparams)
      var routing = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8010/geoserver/wms' , {
        layers: 'IST_Mosaic:pgRouting',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
    });
}
getRoute();
```

Please can anyone suggest a solution to this and point out what I am doing wrong. A screenshot for the results:
[image: The values for x1, y1, x2 and y2 remain undefined]

Comment: `.getLatLng()` method returns `L.LatLng` object, which has coordinates in properties `.lat` and `.lng`, so correct reference would be `start.lng` and `start.lat`.

Comment: Thank u so much. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @TomazicM Please add as an answer

Comment: @Midavalo Yes, eternal dilemma what to do when comment (meaningfully) answers the question: flag question as nonreproducible or turn comment into answer. I also prefer later, but usually do it only when asked by person asking question. There should be some policy about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet marker `.getLatLng()` method returns `L.LatLng` object, which has coordinates in properties `.lat` and `.lng`.

Correct reference to `start` coordinates is then `start.lng` and `start.lat`.